# Why would a fetch operation crash when the amount of data is divisible by 1023 or 1024?

Tags: c#, io, null, windows-ce, dispose

(or perhaps, when divisible by 1023 (see Update 3 below))

I'm chasing a bug that arises when the size of the file containing the data being fetched is divisible by 1024. In that case, the fetch seems to work until complete, but then fails at the very end.

Thinking maybe something strange was being done in such a case (when there was a file whose size was a multiple of 1024), I searched for any reference to "1024" in the code, but there is no live code that specifically mentions "1024."

I did find one thing in the fetching code that I think looks strange, namely this:

```
connFrmSitesData.Dispose();
connFrmSitesData = null;
```

Is this setting of the form to null a possible cause of problems? Is there any reason for it to be there at all?

### UPDATE

I found this code which makes me wonder:

```
string theMessage = new string( '\x00', 1023 );
```

...if it could be tangentially involved in the problem.

### UPDATE 2

Now I see that that string (theMessage)* is not even used; I was able to comment it out (in all three places where it was similarly declared and thereafter not used).

So why in this code there:

```
bool    retVal      = false;            
string  theMessage  = new string( '\x00', 1023 ); // fill 1023 bytes with nulls
. . .
    if( retVal = Util.NetSendCommand( rc.command ) )
```

...is "retVal" the var that has been grayed out (by Resharper, I assume), whereas "theMessage" was NOT grayed out?

- There is also a "normal"** theMessage declared private to the class:

  private string theMessage;

** "Normal" as in it is not instantiated with an overloaded constructor.

### UPDATE 3

I may have located the problem area (actually in a different project - a .DLL that the project calls).

This code is suspect because MAXREAD = 1023.

Can anybody see anything wrong with this that would cause a file of a precise size to fail? e.g., would the call to bReader.Read() fail if the previous Read had gotten everything?

Or is there some other problem lurking in here somewhere?

```
BinaryReader bReader          = null;
. . .
bReader = new BinaryReader( theN_Stream );
. . .
fsWriteText = new FileStream( destFPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write );
. . .
bWriter = new BinaryWriter( fsWriteText );
. . .

/* --------------------------------------- *
 *   Incoming message may be larger than 
 *   the buffer size.
 * --------------------------------------- */ 
int index     = 0;
int indexLast = 0;
int next2Read = MAXREAD;

try
{
    // keep doing this until no data available on the stream, ...
    do
    {
        next2Read         = MAXREAD; //1023
        longString        = "";

    Array.Clear( readbuffer, 0, MAXREAD );

    numberOfBytesRead = bReader.Read( readbuffer, 0, next2Read );

    indexLast  = index;
    realTotBytesRead += numberOfBytesRead; 
    index     += numberOfBytesRead;
    nBytes    += numberOfBytesRead;
    xferProgress = nBytes.ToString() + "|" + fsize.ToString();
    OnProgressChanged(xferProgress);

    if( bWriter != null )
        {
            if( bWriter.BaseStream.CanWrite )
            {
                bWriter.Write( readbuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead );
            }
        }

    if( index >= fsize )
    {
        haveFinishedRead = true;
        break;
    }

    if( !theN_Stream.CanRead )
    {
        break;
    }
} while( index < fsize );
```

### UPDATE 4

In trying to get to the bottom of this problem, I have compiled (no pun intended) the following notes.

// readbuffer is an array of bytes.
// bReader is a binary reader

"index" starts out at 0, is assigned the number of bytes read (either 1023 or the remainder/last bits), later tested against filesize - if equal to or larger, the loop is exited.

"indexLast" starts out at 0, is first assigned the value of index (0 the first time through the loop, thereafter either 1023 or the remainder/last bits), but it is never referenced, so it can be commented out.

"next2Read" is intially assigned MAXREAD, which is 1023. It is used in this line:

```
numberOfBytesRead = bReader.Read( readbuffer, 0, next2Read );
```

...but not referenced thereafter, so it can be removed, and the line above changed to:

```
numberOfBytesRead = bReader.Read( readbuffer, 0, MAXREAD);
```

"longString" is initialized to an empty string, but then not referenced anywhere; however, since it is a global var, perhaps this value is needed elsewhere?

"numberOfBytesRead" is assigned the return value of bReader's Read() method. It is then assigned to "index" and "nBytes". It is then used as the "number of bytes to write" in a call to bWriter.Write().

Like "longString", "realTotBytesRead" is assigned to and then not referenced within this method, but since it is a global var, it may be used elsewhere...

"nBytes" is assigned the value in "numberOfBytesRead", and is then used for the progress bar. It seems that "numberOfBytesRead" could be used and cut out the middle man, but I guess "nBytes" is not hurting anything (except that  mushy pinish grey stuff that keeps my skull from collapsing in on itself)...

"fsize" is used for conditional branching. It is initially set to 0, then set this way:

```
fsize = (int)Int32.Parse( fFileSz );
```

"fFileSz" is a public static string that holds the file size (set elsewhere).

"theN_Stream" is a Network stream.

*When debugging computer programs, you become somewhat of a detective, but rather than chasing bad actors down dark alleys and exposing criminals, you are smoking out bits behaving badly. This sort of detective work is much safer -- more sedentary and sedate, too -- than the other, but what you gain in spared shoeleather and save on life insurance premiums, you lose in ruptured synapses and overwrought brain cells blown sky high, WAY beyond "the cloud"; there's always a tradeoff in everything you do/don't do.*

### UPDATE 5

I now expect the problem is somewhere else, as this code would seem to work whether the filesize is less than, equal to, or greater than MAXREAD (1023). Pseudocode:

//filesize < MAXREAD:

```
if filesize == 1022:
numberOfBytesRead == 1022
index == 1022;
//....breaks out (as it should, it's done), because index == fsize
```

//filesize == MAXREAD: //1023

```
if filesize == 1023:
numberOfBytesRead == 1023
index == 1023;

//breaks out (as it should, it's done), because index == fsize
```

//filesize > MAXREAD:

```
if filesize == 1024:
numberOfBytesRead == 1023
index == 1023;
...continues to loop again:
numberOfBytesRead == 1
index == 1024;
//breaks out (as it should, it's done), because index == fsize
```

// it should be the same for any filesize > MAXREAD

### UPDATE 6

The "magic number" has been found - the app crashes when a file with the size of 190KB is processed. The progress bar that shows the fetch process than freezes up - forever and in every instance when the file size is exactly that; otherwise it is fine (if the filesize is either smaller or larger than 190KB, it works fine).

### UPDATE 7

I realize this is a terrible fix, but the legacy code is so convoluted, [intentionally?] obfuscated, and sleight-of-handish -- with the DLL calling the exe and vice versa, and multiple background threads firing and stopping, flashing and blinking like a strobe light from an insane asylum -- that I brute-forced a temporary fix this way, changing this code:

```
if( processMessage )
{
                Util.ProcessServerResponse( theMessage.Trim( uDelims.ToCharArray() ) );
}
```

...to this:

```
if ( processMessage )
{
                string valToPass = theMessage.Trim(uDelims.ToCharArray());
                if (valToPass.IndexOf("190980") > 0)
                {
                                valToPass = valToPass.Replace("190980", "190978"); 
                }
                Util.ProcessServerResponse( valToPass );
}
```

// Notes: 
1) For some reason, when filesize is 190980, an endless loop occurs in the DLL where "index" (number of bytes already read) remains less than a value representing the total number of bytes to be read - with all other, or the great percentage of all other, filesizes, it works fine...
2) I couldn't use string.Contains() to find "190980" only because it's not available in .NET 1.1

Comment: That code is fine; it cleans up; `using` would be nicer, but is not always possible. Impossible to debug that without some code from around where it is exploding.

Comment: Agree with @MarcGravell - the `Dispose` likely ain't the cause; what's the fetch code look like?

Comment: I would search for 1023 as well...and 1025...feels like a [off-by-one bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)

Comment: does anything else in your code devide by the remainder or anything like that?

Comment: So, you say that file of size 1023 or 1025 doesn't crash the same code? Or, like, file of size 512?

Comment: Based on the bug report, it's only when divisible by 1024. I don't see any 1025 in the code; the only 1023 I see is a string:

string theMessage = new string( '\x00', 1023 );

Comment: As far as showing the code, it's extremely strange - either an utter genius or a complete fool wrote it. To actually show all the directions it flies off in would require practically posting the whole project, and divulage all sorts of company secrets, no doubt, so...

Comment: So Dispose() doesn't already set it to null?

Comment: `Dispose()` will do whatever is defined in `Dispose` on that class; since we don't see the code for that, can't really answer - that said, there is no "magic" to calling `Dispose` - it doesn't set anything to null automatically, it doesn't clean anything up automatically, etc - it does only what it's defined to do.

Comment: Couple of questions: 1) What is the actual exception being thrown (if there is one) 2) You've tagged this as Windows CE - what platform is your code actually running on and what kind of app is it? 3) Have you got any logging in place you can enable?

Comment: @Dash: 1) There isn't one - "the progress bar crashes" 2) It's a .NET 1.1 CE/Compact Framework app 3) No, dagnab it; and I can't debug it as normal - I have to sprinkle MessageBox.Show() to see how far I get. VERY slow and tedious! BTW, are you the cat from Seals and Crofts?

Comment: @ClayShannon I wish I was! Can you reproduce this if you try and read a text file that is exactly 1k (you can create this yourself)? If you do this logic in the GUI thread, and not on a background thread, you can wrap the entry point for a .Net Compact Framework app in a try/catch and get some more info from the exception there. If it's occuring on a background thread then you are out of luck (UnhandledException was only added in .Net CF 2.0) and I'd seriously start thinking about using log4net and adding logging lines to write debug information out.